# nginx serve all domains except one

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, nginx

I have a standard nginx installation on ubuntu 12.04. I want only one subdomain to serve. All others should return 404.

I have defined two sites:

**0-default:**

```
server {
  listen *:80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  listen *:443 default_server ssl;
  listen [::]:443 default_server ssl ipv6only=on;

  return 404;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com.key; 

  server_name _ *.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
}
```

**1-site:**

```
server {
  listen sub.mydomain.com:443;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/sub.mydomain.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/sub.mydomain.com.key;

  root /var/www/sub;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name sub.mydomain.com;
}
```

But 1-site serves all domains on port 443, not only *sub.mydomain.com* and are not served by 0-default.

How could I achieve the wanted behaviour?

Comment: May be that because you mixed ssl directive and ssl option on listen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have explanation.

You 1-site server listens to `ip:port` while defaut site listens to only `port`. When nginx choose which server block to use it prefers most close match and `ip:port` is better match than `port`. And only after that sieving nginx will compare server names, but in this case it's too late. It already nas only one candidate.

After your listen statement alignment they are all "equidistant" from request.

Comment: Yep thats the correct explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it, by aligning the listen statements.

So my listen statements look now as follows:

**0-default:**

```
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen 443 default_server ssl;
```

**1-site:**

```
 listen 443;
```

The subdomain in listen statement seemed to confuse nginx.